# Passing row variables to a function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying create a function where in when you click on a person's name, a list of trainings he/she has attended will show up on another page. My problem right now is how to pass the user_id from each row so that I can use it for my query.

Below is my code so far

Controller:

```
public function traineeRater()
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('level') != 'Rater')
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    $data['trainee'] = $this->rater_model->traineeList();
    $this->load->view('rater/trainee_rater', $data);
}

public function trainingAttended()
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('level') != 'Rater')
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    $data['attended'] = $this->rater_model->getAttended(//some variable here?);

    $this->load->view('rater/attended', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function traineeList()
{
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT dept_name, position, user_id,
                                 CONCAT(fname, ' ', mname, ' ', lname) AS name 
                                 FROM users, department
                                 WHERE users.dept_id = department.dept_id
                                 ");
      return $query->result();
}

public function getAttended($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT training_title, immediate_rater, 
                               CONCAT(fname, ' ', mname, ' ', lname) AS name
                               FROM users, training_details, coach
                               WHERE users.user_id = coach.user_id
                               AND   training_details.dept_id = coach.dept_id
                               AND users.user_id = '".$id."'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

View(traineeList):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
     <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Department</th>
             <th>Position</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <?php foreach ($trainee as $row) 
          {
              ?>
              <tr class = "odd gradeX">
               <td><a href="trainingAttended" style=" text-decoration: none; color: #000000"><?=$row->name;?></a></td>
               <td><?=$row->dept_name;?></td>
               <td><?=$row->position;?></td>
             </tr>
             <?php     
          }
          ?>      
    </tbody>        
 </table>
```

View(trainingAttended):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Training Title</th>
         <th>Immediate Rater</th>
         <th>Coach</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
          foreach ($attended as $row) 
          {
            ?>
            <tr class = "odd gradeX">
                <td><?=$row->training_title;?></td>
                <td><?=$row->immediate_rater;?></td>
                <td><?=$row->name;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php     
          }
          ?>      
      </tbody>        
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<td><a href="trainingAttended/<?= $row->id ?>" style=" text-decoration: none; color: #000000"><?=$row->name;?></a></td>
```

In href make sure you add controller/method/parameters

In controller

```
public function trainingAttended($id)
                                 ^// capture id here
{
if(!$this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
{
    redirect(base_url());
}
if($this->session->userdata('level') != 'Rater')
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url());
}
$data['attended'] = $this->rater_model->getAttended($id);
                                                     ^// send here

$this->load->view('rater/attended', $data);
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's working now, but my UI isn't displaying properly because of the ID displaying in my URL, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Not properly means how??

Comment: oh sorry, let me clarify, I meant the UI isn't loading at all, just the basic html format

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry

Comment: The css links are correct, maybe it's because of the extra parameter in URL

http://localhost:8080/laf2/rater_controller/trainingAttended/3

do I need to rename my view or make a new view?

Answer (score 0):

on your view where you click on a person's name

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(): ?>traineeRater/trainingAttended/<? echo $row->id ?>">Name of person</a>
```

Then on you're Controller:

```
public function trainingAttended()
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('loginuser'))
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    if($this->session->userdata('level') != 'Rater')
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url());
    }

    $id = $this->uri->segment('3');
    $data['attended'] = $this->rater_model->getAttended($id);

    $this->load->view('rater/attended', $data);
}
```

""
Hope it works.

Comment: Put id on a variable on your URL and get the value in the controller using $this->uri->segment();

Comment: nahh Soryy it shoud be 
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(): ?>traineeRater/trainingAttended/<? echo $row->id ?>">Name of person</a>

in you view where you click person's name.